# Html code more simple than that ..TTFB Large

Tags: php

I have the next code :

```
<table id="tabel_linie_<?php echo $id_linie ?>

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <style="text-align:left" <h4>Linia
                <?php echo $nume_linie ?>
                </h4>
        </th>
        <th>Referinta</th>
        <th>Cantitate OK</th>
        <th>Numar Operatori</th>
        <th>Cantitate NOK</th>
        <th>Ora Inceput</th>
        <th>Ora Sfarsit</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody style="text-align: left">
    <?php if (!isset($valori_vechi)||($valori_vechi==false)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><strong><?php echo $nume_linie ?></strong>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_linie ?>" name="id_linie[]" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="referinta[]" style="height:30px">
                <option value="0">--Selecteaza referinta--</option>
                <?php 
                  foreach ($referinte_linie as $referinta) { 
                    echo "<option value='".$referinta->id_produs."' >"; 
                    echo $referinta->referinta.$referinta->index_produs; 
                    echo "</option>"; 
                  }
                ?>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input style="width:60px;border:1px solid green;text-align:center;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;height:16px" type="text" value="" name="cantitate_ok[]" />
        </td>
        <td>

            <input style="width:60px;border:1px solid #999;text-align:center;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;height:16px" type=text " value=" "name ="numar_operatori[] "/></td>
```

This code call from database a number of lines an after that for each line call "referinta" for each line  which are the same for all the line selected.

The problem is that it takes to long to open the page.I have TTFB  more than 15 Seconds.

Have anyone an idea how to make this going faster ?

Answer (score 1):

long TTFB is a server-side issue. Improving your html won't help.

It usually means that the server is taking too long to build the response.

This can be have numerous root cause :

- Bad SQL queries
- bad code
- etc.

try to find the culprit, good luck :)

**Hint**: Here your PHP code seems fine, I think it is your SQL query that is taking too long to execute.

Also note that your HTML code is wrong :

- You are not closing your `table` element : `<table id="tabel_linie_<?php echo $id_linie ?>`
- You have a style element in your body (which is bad practice) with no closing tag (`>`) :

  ```
  <th>
      <style="text-align:left" <h4>Linia
          <?php echo $nume_linie ?>
          </h4>
  </th>
  ```

Comment: Thank you  for comment .. table element is closed ...after the the all code .. and i removed the style element .

Comment: You don't have the closing sign (>) on the table

Comment: I do`nt now why here isn`t because ..in my php file ai have it                <table id="tabel_linie_<?php echo $id_linie ?>">

Answer (score 0):

**Web front end:**

Check that the HTML is entirely valid. To shorten the HTML use CSS classes.
If the rows each have the same `<select>...</select>` with many options load them once dynamically: search key: AJAX+JavaScript.

**Back end:**

Check the SQL. An extra index might be needed, the query a bit smarter.

Maybe pagination of the table.